# Partitioning Windows 7 so I can use ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, music

I have been recording happily using Audacity for many years but after upgrading to Windows 7, the latency has meant that recording music is impossible.  My mate suggested partitioning my hard drive, installing ubuntu on it and then using this alongside Windows.  He reckons I can use music recording software then on the partitioned Ubuntu drive without the latency problems.

A few questions:

1. Is my mate correct?
2. How do I go about doing the partition and installing?
3. What music recording software would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If the latency is an effect of the Windows software, then it's possible that he's correct. I would follow the partitioning instructions here: [Resize Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions)

There are some decisions to be made as to which boot loader to use (Ubuntu's boot menu or use Windows boot menu).  After the partitions are resized, I would follow the rest of the instructions in this walk-thru: [Ubuntu dual-install from bootable CD-drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

#### Which boot menu?

As far as I can tell, there is no general agreement on this answer.  But one concern that I thought was important to note was that certain Windows antivirus applications might cause problems if they notice changes to the Master Boot Record.  If that's a concern for you, I heard that [EasyBCD is the way to go](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). Even so, I personally use Ubuntu's boot manager.

Another concern from a different website is that if you update or upgrade your Windows 7, it will rewrite your Master Boot Record anyway (deleting your entry if you use Ubuntu's loader).  You can [read more for that here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/).

Comment: Cheers Clayton.  Advice much appreciated.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if it worked for you.  Thanks.